# Ionic custom keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm trying to build a custom keyboard on Ionic.

I'm targeting iOS and Android devices.
I have a searchbar and my goal is to display a keyboard and just above it add a **button** that would, when clicked, open something in the place where the keyboard is.

I'm trying to use the @ionic-native/keyboard module but I didn't find any help on the internet. Plus the keyboard doesn't show when I try to display on a navigator, I have to type with my computer keyboard in the searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Doesn't supported in computer browser you need to check in real mobile devises

use ionic cordova run android This will start an android emulator that should allow all the cordova plugins to function